# "int object is not callable" error using PuLP code

Tags: python, typeerror, linear-programming, pulp

I'm just learning how the PuLP library works, which is a linear programming solver. 
The code I'm using was found here: [LINK](https://medium.com/opex-analytics/optimization-modeling-in-python-pulp-gurobi-and-cplex-83a62129807a). It solves the following optimization problem (in this case, using binary variables x_{ij}):

[image]

This is the code from the tutorial:

```
import random
import pulp as plp

#Creating random constants for the model's input
n = 10
m = 5
set_I = range(1, n+1)
set_J = range(1, m+1)
c = {(i,j): random.normalvariate(0,1) for i in set_I for j in set_J}
a = {(i,j): random.normalvariate(0,5) for i in set_I for j in set_J}
l = {(i,j): random.randint(0,10) for i in set_I for j in set_J}
u = {(i,j): random.randint(10,20) for i in set_I for j in set_J}
b = {j: random.randint(0,30) for j in set_J}

opt_model = plp.LpProblem(name="Binary Model")


# if x is Binary
x_vars  = {(i,j):
plp.LpVariable(cat=plp.LpBinary, name="x_{0}_{1}".format(i,j)) 
for i in set_I for j in set_J}


# Less than equal constraints
constraints = {j : opt_model.addConstraint(
plp.LpConstraint(
             e=m(a[i,j] * x_vars[i,j] for i in set_I),
             sense=plp.plp.LpConstraintLE,
             rhs=b[j],
             name="constraint_{0}".format(j)))
       for j in set_J}

objective = plp.lpSum(x_vars[i,j] * c[i,j] 
                    for i in set_I 
                    for j in set_J)

# for minimization
opt_model.sense = plp.LpMinimize
opt_model.setObjective(objective)
```

And I'm getting the following error that I don't understand:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-08e33a7305cc> in <module>
     28              rhs=b[j],
     29              name="constraint_{0}"))
---> 30        for j in set_J}
     31 
     32 objective = plp.lpSum(x_vars[i,j] * c[i,j] 

<ipython-input-20-08e33a7305cc> in <dictcomp>(.0)
     28              rhs=b[j],
     29              name="constraint_{0}"))
---> 30        for j in set_J}
     31 
     32 objective = plp.lpSum(x_vars[i,j] * c[i,j] 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Aside: `import pulp as plp` do you really benefit from a name that's one character shorter but significantly harder to read?

Comment: I mentioned that I didn't write that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains the following as an argument to `plp.LpConstraint`:

```
e=m(a[i,j] * x_vars[i,j] for i in set_I)
```

`m` is defined as an int, but is being called as a function. It should instead be:

```
e=plp.lpSum(a[i,j] * x_vars[i,j] for i in set_I)
```

This is the cause of the error, and appears to just be a typo in your guide. Another typo in the very same expression is that `plp.plp.LpConstraintLE` should just be `plp.LpConstraintLE`.

Once you clean up those two errors, you should be unblocked, and continuing with `opt_model.solve()` will solve the model.

---

You might find the following to be more readable code to work with to solve this problem in pulp, for instance using nice pulp features like `LpVariable.dicts`. Something I've always liked about pulp is that the model creation code is actually pretty readable.

```
import pulp

### Create n, m, set_I, set_J, c, a, l, u, and b as before

# Model
opt_mod = pulp.LpProblem(name="Binary_model", sense=pulp.LpMinimize)

# Variables from a dictionary
x_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", c.keys(), cat=pulp.LpBinary)

# Constraints
for j in set_J:
    opt_mod += pulp.lpSum(a[i,j] * x_vars[i,j] for i in set_I) <= b[j]

# Objective
opt_mod += pulp.lpSum(c[i,j] * x_vars[i,j] for i,j in c)

# Solve
opt_mod.solve()

# Which variables are set?
print([x for x in x_vars if x_vars[x].varValue > 0.999])
```